# Validar si un dato existe en una tabla MySql para continuar con el Storage Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Quisiera saber como puedo validar si existe un dato en una tabla para continuar con un SP.

Por ejemplo,

Tengo la tabla ACADEMIA y ATLETA. Para que un atleta pueda registrarse a nombre de una academia, la academia ya tiene que existir en la tabla ACADEMIA. Por el momento, solo tengo el SP creado para insertar, pero necesito validar ese parametro.

**Tabla ACADEMIA**

```
CREATE TABLE `ACADEMIA`(
ID_ACA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE_ACA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
DIRECCION_ACA VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
PAIS_ACA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PROVINCIA_ACA VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
DISTRITO_ACA VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ACADEMIA
PRIMARY KEY(ID_ACA)
);
```

**Tabla ATLETA**

```
CREATE TABLE `ATLETA`(
ID_ATLETA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_ACADEMIA INT NOT NULL, /*FOREIGN KEY*/
NOMBRE_AT VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
CEDULA_AT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ANO_NAC_AT VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
NOM_ACADEMIA_AT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CAT_PESO_AT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
SEXO_AT CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CATEGORIA_AT CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
NUM_TEL_AT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMAIL_AT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CINT_CAT_AT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CKC_ATLETA_SEXO
CHECK (SEXO_AT IN ('M', 'F')),
CONSTRAINT CKC_ATLETA_CATEGORIA
CHECK (CATEGORIA_AT IN ('K', 'P', 'PP', 'PE')),
CONSTRAINT PK_ATLETA
PRIMARY KEY(ID_ATLETA),
CONSTRAINT FK_ATLETA_ACADEMIA
FOREIGN KEY(ID_ACADEMIA)
REFERENCES ACADEMIA(ID_ACA)
);
```

**STORAGE PROCEDURE PARA INSERTAR ATLETAS**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ATLETA_INSERTAR(
ID_ACADEMIA INT,
NOMBRE_AT VARCHAR(60),
CEDULA_AT VARCHAR(20),
ANO_NAC_AT VARCHAR(5),
NOM_ACADEMIA_AT VARCHAR(100),
CAT_PESO_AT VARCHAR(10),
SEXO_AT CHAR(1),
CATEGORIA_AT CHAR(1),
NUM_TEL_AT VARCHAR(30),
EMAIL_AT VARCHAR(100),
CINT_CAT_AT VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    IF(SEXO_AT = 'M' OR SEXO_AT = 'F') AND (CATEGORIA_AT = 'K' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'P' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'PP' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'PE') THEN 
    INSERT INTO ATLETA (ID_ACADEMIA, NOMBRE_AT, CEDULA_AT, ANO_NAC_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT, CAT_PESO_AT, SEXO_AT, CATEGORIA_AT, NUM_TEL_AT, EMAIL_AT, CINT_CAT_AT) VALUES (ID_ACADEMIA, NOMBRE_AT, CEDULA_AT, ANO_NAC_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT, CAT_PESO_AT, SEXO_AT, CATEGORIA_AT, NUM_TEL_AT, EMAIL_AT, CINT_CAT_AT);
    END IF;
END//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer paso es pasar el id de dicha Academia a través de parámetros al hacer el llamado del procedimiento.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ATLETA_INSERTAR(IN parametro INT)
```

luego dentro de tu procedimiento debes hacer una consulta a la tabla correspondiente, previamente debes haber declarado la variable a usar con

```
DECLARE Existe INT;
```

Seteas la variable

```
SET Existe = (SELECT id FROM ACADEMIA WHERE id=parametro);
```

y en base a esa variable ejecutas la inserción.

```
 IF (Existe IS NOT NULL) THEN
      // Ejecutas la insercion 
 ELSE 
      // solo sales del procedimiento
 END IF;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudó muchisimo.

Comment: Excelente!!. saludos.